# Activity calling other activities on Android sequence

Tags: android, android-activity, onresume

How can I save and remember the activity that got launched by a specific activity? Say I have activity 1 which launches activity 2 using startActivityForResult(). 
Then I see the following sequence of calls:

```
       onPause called from Activity1!
       onSaveInstanceState called from Activity1
       onActivityResult called from Activity1
```

Later when I hit the back button to go back to Activity1 from Activity2, I see the onRestart called:

```
       onRestart called from Activity1
       onResume called from Activity1
```

So my question now is how do I identify that the transition is from Activity2 -> Activity1 rather than (say) Activity3 -> Activity1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible way is to use `startActivityFprResult` instead. When you finish any of your other Activities (in this case Activity2 or Activity3), you call `setResult(RESULT_OK, intent)` and provide an `Intent`. This will be delivered to Activity1 in `onActivityResult`, and you can just put some extra in the `Intent` to identify which `Activity` just finished.

Comment: But where can I save the information I get in onActivityResult()? I assume it is called after Activity2 or Activity3 are launched correct? What I want is to figure out when Activity1 is *restarted* is which activity (2 or 3) was running just before. Is this possible to do?

Comment: You get `onActivityResult` when the activity you opened with `startActivityForResult` finishes. It is not called after Activity2 _launches_, it is called after Activity2 _finishes_ and you come back to Activity1.